# How to run AsyncTask to return response from server, then segue to next view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, segue, xcode8

I can segue to the next view controller after I get the response with the below code but it takes about 10 seconds.  The print(result) prints the response in less then a second but the segue takes 10 seconds.  If I put the segue under the getResponse function the segue and the print(result) line will run in under a second but the label I'm trying to update on the next view controller using the checkit string doesn't update the label on loading the next view controller.

Function:

```
func getResponse(urrl: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: urrl)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                completion("")
            } else {
                if let returnData = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                    completion(returnData)


                } else {
                    completion("")
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

Calling the function and segue:

```
getResponse(urrl:finalurl) { result in
                        print(result)
                        checkit = result
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "responsesegue", sender:self)
                }
```

Next View Controller:

class WebResponse: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var responseMessage: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(checkit + " Next Spot") //just posts the default checkit value
    responseMessage.text = checkit

}



}
```

Update:

Calling function and segue:

```
getResponse(urrl:finalurl) { result in
                        print(result)
                        var message = result.components(separatedBy: "\"")
                        print(message[5])
                        self.holdon = message[5]
                        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "responsesegue", sender:self)
                }


                func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? WebResponse {
                        destinationViewController.checkit  = self.holdon
                    }
                }
```

Web Response:

```
import UIKit

class WebResponse: UIViewController {
    var checkit = "l"
    @IBOutlet weak var responseMessage: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(checkit + " Next Spot")
        //var ccheckit = "Testttttting"
        responseMessage.text = checkit

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



}
```

I defined holdon in the first view controller in the same place as the checkit is defined in the second view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your completion block in main queue like this:

```
func getResponse(urrl: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: urrl)!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
               DispatchQueue.main.async{
                completion("")
               }
            } else {
                if let returnData = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                      completion(returnData)
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                      completion("")
                    }
                }
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

when you call the function perform segue in main queue

```
getResponse(urrl:finalurl) { result in
     DispatchQueue.main.async{
       print(result)
       checkit = result
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "responsesegue", sender:self)      
    }

}
```

Comment: Haha just figured it out and came to post the answer but you beat me to it. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Putting `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "responsesegue", sender:self)` under your `getResponse` is correct. To pass data, you need to implement `prepareForSegue` in this way:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? WebResponse {
        destinationViewController.checkit  = self.checkit
    }
}
```

Comment: destinationViewController.checkit is giving me an error saying "Value of type 'WebResponse' has no member 'checkit'.  Do I need to define check it in WebResponse?  Right now it is just created outside the first view controller class, as a global variable

Comment: @JonnyMan Yes. Using a global variable is not a good practice. Passing data though segue is the best practice. So first remove define your `checkit` in your first view controller not to be global. They create it again in your `WebResponse `

Comment: Hmm now its just freezes up when I get to the function that triggers the getResponse function and the segue

Comment: @JonnyMan Ok. Did you see `print(result)` getting executed?

Comment: I keep getting this errror:  2017-06-27 21:04:15.974600-0600 My Concert Club[15569:670358] [Common] _BSMachError: port 9c07; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"

Comment: @JonnyMan This error looks weird. Where did it happen?